# PHP cannot retrieve serialized data from the database

Tags: php, serialization

I am trying to retrieve serialized data from the database, but when do foreach nothing print-out on the screen

```
   <?php
   $query = mysqli_query($dbConnection,"SELECT job_category_id FROM jobs");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $job_category_id = $row['job_category_id'];
    
      $test = unserialize($job_category_id);
      foreach($test as $datas){
      echo $datas;
     }
    }
  ?>
```

So I tried to test through the following examples...

**1.**

```
//echo from the server
echo $job_category_id;
```

**Output when echo from the server**

```
s:1:\"4\";
a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"4\";i:1;s:1:\"3\";}
a:3:{i:0;s:0:\"\";i:1;s:1:\"5\";i:2;s:1:\"4\";}
a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"4\";i:1;s:1:\"3\";}
```

**2.**

```
//var_dump() from the server "WITHOUT unserialize"
    var_dump($job_category_id);
```

**Output When var_dump() from the server "WITHOUT unserialize"**

```
string(10) "s:1:\"4\";" string(34) "a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"4\";i:1;s:1:\"3\";}" string(47) "a:3:{i:0;s:0:\"\";i:1;s:1:\"5\";i:2;s:1:\"4\";}" string(34) "a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"4\";i:1;s:1:\"3\";}"
```

**3.**

```
//unserialize then var_dump()    
$test = unserialize($job_category_id);
var_dump($test);
```

**Output when unserialize then do var_dump()**

```
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
```

Comment: You must be mistaken somehow. None of those items outputs `false` when you try to unserialize it. Live demo: https://3v4l.org/i7510 . The first one produces a warning because the unserialised data isn't an array, so you can't loop through it. But the others are fine. Please provide a [mre] of the issue if you need further help. Thanks.

Comment: All of your serialized data is corrupt and shouldn't have those backslashes. I would wager that you ran it through some kind of "sanitization" before you inserted it which corrupted it, because that's generally what those do. Show the code that inserted the data and we might be able to help recover, and also suggest how not to break your data in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The problem because of back slash `"\"` stores inside the serialized array
`a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"4\";i:1;s:1:\"3\";}`   The back slash here causing problems when unserialize it

to avoid this we have to encode the serialize before storing into the database, and decoding while unserializing like the below example

```
base64_encode(serialize($_POST['jobCatID']));
unserialize(base64_decode($job_category_id));
```

Comment: _"to avoid this we have to encode the serialize before storing into the database"_ - no, we don't. What we instead have to _stop_ doing, is whatever botched attempt at "securing" the data was made during its insertion into the database.

Comment: Hello @CBroe , when I used encode to the serialze it solved "\" problem, do you have better recommendation to avoid the "\"